# Webpack runtime conditional module resolution

Tags: webpack, es6-modules, es6-module-loader

I have an app that uses a core directory, and besides the core, I have different directories that contain classes that extend core classes and have slightly modified logic.

I got a file tree like below.

```
app
|-- core
|   |-- x
|   |-- y
|   |-- z
|   `-- plugins
|       |-- xyz-helper.js
|      
|-- slightly-modified-logic
|   `-- plugins
|       |-- xyz-helper.js
```

I want to use existing Webpack functionality to achieve something similar to a "theming" solution. You have a subtheme where you can override parent theme templates, if you don't override a specific template, it's gonna use the parent theme.

So, in my case, the ideal scenario would be:

1) Mount `slightly-modified-logic` directory

2) Dependencies in core classes should be resolved using the mounted directory, if the mounted directory does not provide an implementation of its own, only then fall back to core classes themselves.

I checked `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin` but that seems useful only if you wanna affect the entire build, I want the bundle to include everything, that or module chunk for each non-core directory that I load on demand.

The way I'm thinking of doing this is by building a `resolve` map, assuming I can chain path custom aliases, and Webpack tries all of those before falling back to normal resolution. But how do I do that @ runtime? The decision to mount a different directory than core should be taken based on runtime parameters.

I only need some hints, thanks.

Comment: I dont think this is possible. Overloading "import" beats the entire purpose of packing files, so I'm generating different bundles and load them as needed via a custom bundle manager. Still, starting a bounty, hoping to hear different approaches.

Comment: Have you looked at using ["Webpack and Dynamic Imports"](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/webpack-and-dynamic-imports-doing-it-right-72549ff49234) to load the themes?

Comment: Omg, that's it. I looked into dynamic imports, but I missed the "magic comments" part. Thanks a lot. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Webpack dynamic imports. You can check the documentation on ["Weback - Dynamic expressions in import()"](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import)
. A part of the modules path should be specified, for example if we have a `themes` directory, we can load the corresponding theme plugins/code like so:

```js
import(`themes/${themeName}/config.js`);
import(`themes/${themeName}/plugins/plugin.js`);
```

Assume we have a file structure:

```
themes
├─ themeA
│  └─ plugins
│     └─ plugin.js
└─ themeB
   └─ plugins
      └─ plugin.js
```

And the contents for each `plugin.js` file:

```js
// themeA/plugins/plugin.js
export const thePlugin = () => console.log('Plugin A');

// themeB/plugins/plugin.js
export const thePlugin = () => console.log('Plugin B');
```

We can use dynamic imports like this:

```js
let theme = 'themeA';

import(`./themes/${theme}/plugins/plugin.js`).then(({ thePlugin }) => {
  thePlugin();
}); 

theme = 'themeB';

import(`./themes/${theme}/plugins/plugin.js`).then(({ thePlugin }) => {
  thePlugin();
});
```

And the output will be:

```
Plugin A
Plugin B
```

You can read a nice article about ["Webpack and dynamic import"](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/webpack-and-dynamic-imports-doing-it-right-72549ff49234).

Comment: For anyone that might be looking for this. Using what's in the answer means, you'd still have to refactor existing imports, there's no magic resolution. However, the magic comments seem to be really powerful. I'll give them a try.

Comment: Yes, magic comments are very powerful and provide much flexibility in such cases. Do you want to add remarks regarding magic comments to the answer? Of course you can edit the answer and add any additional information you may want.